# File Permissions: Who are the user, group, and others on my web server? What perms should i use for uploaded files, php files, etc.?

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, file-permissions, upload

I am using cPanel with apache 2 and php 5.2. I have a file upload script, which currently puts the uploaded files in a directory with 0777 perms and the file itself also has 0777 perms. this is because with other perms, i would be thrown an "Invalid Access" error.

so, what perms should i use so that the files are secure, but can still be accessed when a user wants to download them via my download script?

Comment: Well, seeing that with permissions any different from 0777 you get the "Invalid Access" error, you don't really have much of a choice, do you?
But maybe there is something you could do. Do you control the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you the SysAdmin of this server?

If you are then I have just answered a very similar question here

[Apache DSO file permissions 777](https://serverfault.com/questions/170319/apache-dso-file-permissions-777)

If not you need to question if you're happy to have you site on this server at all.